# Two Oracle TNS Listener

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tns

When I want to connect to my database in SQLDeveloper i get a TNS listener error message. 
When I stop the OracleOraClient11g_home1_32bitTNSListener in my Services and retry to connect it works fine. Then the OracleXETnsListener is running.
How can I avoid stopping the one listener that the other can start?

I've two listener.ora files where Port 1521 is configured. So I assume it has to do with the ports?

[image: two tns listener]

[image]

Comment: Yes; but why do you want to run two listeners? What error do you get?

Comment: see update. When I terminate the running oracleClient11g TNS Listener it works. then the XETNS Listener is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On any operating system, you are not allowed to have 2 processes listening on the same port (in this case 1521) on the same network inteface (I'm going to assume you have only 1 network interface). Otherwise how would the operating system know which process to hand the port connection over to!

As Alex has mentioned you do not need to run multiple listeners. Disable one of the services and edit the listener.ora which points to the correct service - by default this is under the oracle_home/network/admin directory but if you have changed the TNS_ADMIN variable value on the system it will be there. You can add another listener for the SID/Service Name if you wish, but in the case of Windows it will automatically pick up all the Instances running on the system.

Just in case you really do want to run 2 listeners (you would only need to do this if you have a very old RDBMS version for example) you can edit one of the listener.ora files and change the port to say 1522. An example is below:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ROBS)(PORT = 1522))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

You then change the tnsnames.ora for the connect to point to that port like this:

```
SCN =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ROBS)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = SCN)
    )
  )
```

Or with SQLDeveloper you can change the port directly on the IDE with the TNS direct option if that's how you have it configured.